# How can I make multiple D3.js transitions that repeat at an unchanging rate?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to simulate waves in D3 and, as you can see in the fiddle below, the waves--multiple rectangles that transition up and down in height--change in their duration to go from what appears to a single rolling wave to a bunch of rectangles bouncing up and down. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: The visualization starts like this]

[image: and soon looks like this]

This is where the magic happens:

```
for (let i = 0; i < numRects; i++) {
  const height = scaleY(seaLevel)
  const bar = svg.append('rect')
    .attr('fill', 'blue')
    .attr('opacity', 0.7)
    .attr('x', i * barWidth + xMargin)
    .attr('width', barWidth)
    .datum({delay: i * 20})

    // add movement
    function repeat (start) {
      const low = scaleY(seaLevel - height)
      const high = scaleY(seaLevel + height)
      bar
        .attr('y', waveBoxHeight - low)
        .attr('height', low)
        .transition()
          .ease(d3.easeQuad)
          .delay((d) => (start) ? d.delay : 0)
          .duration(1000)
          .attr('y', waveBoxHeight - high)
          .attr('height', high)
          .transition()
            .ease(d3.easeQuad)
            .duration(1000)
            .attr('y', waveBoxHeight - low)
            .attr('height', low)
            .on('end', repeat)
    }
    repeat(true)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bts9bpdz/

Comment: `.on('end'` is called when **each** bar completes it's transition.  You probably only want to call `repeat` when **all** bars complete transition.  See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bts9bpdz/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the [chained transition](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1125997) strategy described in this bl.ock. See this [modified wave example](http://blockbuilder.org/gcalmettes/b6b8cd0f3454337771a0226f75b585c4) to fit your needs.